# Cannot make mobile broadband connection in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, networking, usb, internet

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and I bought yesterday a Vodafone USB stick for internet connection. I am located in Romania.

This is what I've did:

**First Thing**

1. Network Connections, added connection.
2. Selected Mobile broadband
3. Selected my country, and network (vodafone)
4. Selected Mobile Internet (Postpaid) I've called the guy who gave me the stick, and he told me it's Postpaid (anyway, I've tried also prepaid, not working).
5. Just got to general, and checked Automatically connect to this network when it is available, and saved.

Nothing happend.

**Second thing**

I've installed wvdial, set up the configuration to

```
Phone = *99#
Username = internet.vodafone.ro
Password = vodafone
New PPPD = yes
stupid mode = 1
```

When I run `sudo wvdial` I get this

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
```

I don't have any /dev/modem file or folder, and also no file starting with the name ttyUSB.

**Third thing**

I've took out of the USB port the stick, and run ls -1 /dev > before.txt. Plugged in the stick, and runned again.
The diff before.txt after.txt got me this:

```
9a10
> cdrom2
82a84
> sg2
86a89
> sr1
```

**Fourth thing**

If I run `lsusb` I get this

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1f17 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21bc Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 064e:8123 Suyin Corp.
```

This one (I guess) is the usb stick

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1f17 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

Any suggestions ?

The usb works fine on windows. I've tried to install it's own software (windows application) with wine, but also got an error.

**UPDATE:**

I've found a command that tells me which /dev/* is my Vodafone Stick.

**sudo lsblk**

```
sr1     11:1    1   128M  0 rom  /media/icebox/Vodafone Mobile Broadband
```

I've changed my wvdial configuration file, and added:

```
Modem = /dev/sr1
```

Now, if I run **sudo wvdial** I get:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot open /dev/sr1: Invalid argument
--> Cannot open /dev/sr1: Invalid argument
--> Cannot open /dev/sr1: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Mobile broadband devices usually get called something like `wwan0` can you add the output of `ifconfig -a`

Comment: I have only etho (ethernet) eth1 (wi-fi card) and lo, that's all

Comment: Can you add the output of `ifconfig -a` please

Comment: `/dev/sr1` is a optical media. The stick has one storage media and the actual device. The most probable bet is `/dev/sg2`. The `lsblk` shows volumes/partition/media not devices.

Answer (score 1):

Linux detected your USB-modem as disk. You need to disable CD-mode and storage-mode. It's possible with "usb-modeswitch". Or you can to use special AT-commands.

[Manual in ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Huawei_E1550_3G_modem).

Comment: thanks, I think I get the idea now, still I've tried to change the usb_modeswitch config, but still the same.

Comment: Try to use AT-comands for your modem.

Comment: Also maybe: your mobile operator locked modem - model work only with specific program. In this case you can unlock modem using "QPST" (or analogs).

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by OP:

> It was VERY simple:
>
> ```
> cd /media/icebox/Vodafone
> ./install
> ```
>
> Before you try anything with wvdial or usb_modeswitch, check what's on
>   the usb. Reason why I haven't checked the media for installation on
>   linux is because the guys from Vodafone didn't even knew how to
>   install it on linux, so I thought it's no installation file for linux.